# replace characters in a list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I am doing a hangman projec, and I am having trouble checking words with multiple identicle letters, such as "elephant"

my current way of doing it:

```
enter_number = int(input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list:"))
chosen_word = words[enter_number]
ini_guess = "_"*len(chosen_word)
list_01 = list(ini_guess)

if letter_input in chosen_word:
    for letter in chosen_word:
        if letter == letter_input:
            list_01.pop(chosen_word.index(letter_input))
            list_01.insert(chosen_word.index(letter_input),letter_input)
            print("The letter is in the word")
                print("Letters matched so far:","".join(list_01))
```

Comment: Define 'having trouble'. What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: AFAIK , in a hangman game, if you guess a letter, dont you fill all the blanks where the letter comes in? You dont need to map the letter to its blank in case of multiple occurances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating the whole list once with that `in`, then iterating it again with that `for`, the iterating it again with each `index` call. That's not just wasteful performance, it's also overcomplicated and easier to get wrong.

In fact, almost every time you think you want `list.index`, you actually don't, because you will have trouble with duplicate values—exactly the problem you're running into. If you ask for the index of `e` in `elephant`, there's no way the list can know whether you want `2` instead of `0`. The only way to know that is to keep track of the index as you go along—e.g., with the `enumerate` function.

So, a better solution is to just loop once:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(chosen_word):
    if letter == letter_input:
        list_01[i] = letter_input
        print("The letter is in the word")
        print("Letters matched so far:","".join(list_01))
```

Once you've simplified it like this, you'll notice a second problem: you're printing "The letter is in the word" once for each time it appears, instead of just once, and you're also printing "Letters matched so far" once for each time it appears—which means not at all, if it doesn't appear at all. But now it should be a lot more obvious how to fix that problems.

If you understand list comprehensions and `zip`, it might be even clearer to simplify it farther:

```
list_01 = [letter_input if letter_input == letter else oldval
           for oldval, letter in zip(list_01, chosen_word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid `pop` and `insert`, list comprehensions are easier to read:

Also, string's are not great to work with when you want to replace them letter by letter. Better off with a list of chars.

```
matches = ['_' for _ in chosen_word]
```

I'm not sure why you are having the user input an integer when you are trying to implement hangman, do you not want them to guess letters? Say you get a letter from the user and name it `letter`:

```
mask = [x == letter for x in chosen_word]
```

Now you have a list of booleans, True if the letter matches at this position, and false otherwise. Replace letters in the matches list with:

```
for index, bool in enumerate(mask):
    if bool == True:
        matches[index] = letter
```

Say the word was "elephant" and they guessed "e", then `''.join(matches)` would print `'e_e_____'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerate() to get both the index and the letter at the index

```
if letter_input in chosen_word:
    for i,letter in enumerate(chosen_word):
        if letter == letter_input:
            list_01[i] = letter_input
            print("The letter is in the word")
            print("Letters matched so far:","".join(list_01))
```